# numpy knn with vectorizing nested matrices

Tags: python, numpy, knn, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to implement the KNN algorithm with numpy and its vectorizing.

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[11,12,13], [21,22,23], [31,32,33]])
B = np.array([[41,42,43], [51,52,53], [61,62,63]])
C = np.array([[71,72,73], [81,82,83], [91,92,93]])

X = np.array([A, B, C])

f = lambda a,b: (a-b)**2
np.sqrt(np.vectorize(f)(A, X).reshape(3,9).sum(axis=1))
# array([   0.,   90.,  180.])
```

If I use it this way, I get a 3x1 matrix of the distances of all vectors to A.

To get all distances of all vectors to each other, I would need a result matrix as follows:

```sh
array([[   0.,   90.,  180.],
       [  90.,    0.,   90.],
       [ 180.,   90.,    0.]])
```

How can I improve the operation so that I get the desired result?

Comment: What's the point in using the `np.vectorize`?  You should be able to do subtraction and power of the arrays without that.  That function is meant for complex functions that can only be expressed in terms of scalars.

Comment: You can write KNN algorithm in pure python. Then ask how to rewrite it to numpy code. Which work better I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [843]: np.sqrt(f(X[:,None],X).reshape(3,3,9).sum(axis=-1))
Out[843]: 
array([[   0.,   90.,  180.],
       [  90.,    0.,   90.],
       [ 180.,   90.,    0.]])
```

You don't need `vectorize`.  `f` works with arrays directly.

But looking at

```
In [841]: f(X[:,None],X).reshape(3,3,9)
Out[841]: 
array([[[   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [ 900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900],
        [3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600]],

       [[ 900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
        [ 900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900]],

       [[3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600, 3600],
        [ 900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900,  900],
        [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0]]], dtype=int32)
```

makes me suspect you are calculating more values than needed.  But I haven't tried to look at the bigger picture.

Comment: Thank you a lot! Numpy's indexing is sometimes really hard to understand.  You're also right about the complexity of the calculation.